# How to change Log in link to log out link in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, authentication, logout

On the login page I have used this log in link and I want to change the link to log out link when the user log in. Would be grateful.

Login.aspx

```
<div id="header">
        <div class="loginDisplay">
 [ <a href="~/Login.aspx" id="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server">Log In</a> ]

</div>
```

Code Behind Login.aspx

```
  public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbInfo.Enabled = false;
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strcon = "Data Source=MUNIZA\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=LD_Server;Integrated Security=True";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("spStudentProfile", con);

        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("RegNo", TextBox2.Text);

        SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("Password", TextBox1.Text);

        com.Parameters.Add(p1);
        com.Parameters.Add(p2);
        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader rd = com.ExecuteReader();
        if (rd.HasRows)
        {
            rd.Read();
            Response.Redirect("~/Home.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            lbInfo.Enabled = true;
            lbInfo.Text = "Invalid username or password.";
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: how do you check user logged or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It's more secure** if you use one of the asp.net membership techniques to log-in your users and check their authorities, but here is a quick solution to what you are trying to do based on your code:

simply add a session property and make the following changes on your code to achieve what you want:

```
public bool IsAuthenticated
{
   get { return Convert.ToBoolean(Session["sIsAuthenticated"] ?? false); }
   set { Session["sIsAuthenticated"] = value; }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //your codes ...

    if (rd.HasRows)
    {
        IsAuthenticated = true;
        //your codes ...
    }
    else
    {
        IsAuthenticated = false;
        //your codes ...
    }
 }
```

and now in your .aspx page you could have something like this:

```
<div id="header">
 <div class="loginDisplay">
 <%: IsAuthenticated ?  "[ <a href='" + ResolveUrl("~/Logout.aspx") + "'>Log Out</a> ]" : 
                        "[ <a href='" + ResolveUrl("~/Login.aspx") + "'>Log In</a> ]" %>
</div>
```

Now your logged-in user is valid till the session gets expire.

Update 1

replace this part for the other pages:

```
       <%: Session["sIsAuthenticated"].toString ()  == "true" : ...
```

**UPDATE 2** (another way) place this code on the other pages

```
 <%
    string url = "~/Login.aspx", text = "Log in";
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(Session["sIsAuthenticated"] ?? false))
    { url = "~/Logout.aspx"; text = "Log out"; }
 %>
<a href="<%: ResolveUrl(url) %>"><%: text %></a>
```

Now on page load logout.aspx.cs code behind you should kill the session on page load and redirect user to another page to take the action completely.

Logout.aspx.cs

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session.Remove("sIsAuthenticated");
        Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
    }
```

Comment: What if I use the log in link on another page?

Comment: You just use the code above(first section) in your login code behind once and you could use the link(second section) anywhere in your web forms.

Comment: When I am using it on other pages it says, "IsAuthenticated does not exist in the current context".

Comment: That's right becuase the value of IsAuthenticated is valid but the property is not valid in the other pages, you should either use the session value in your page or put the IsAuthenticared in a base page class.

Comment: I put this on every page and it is working now,
    `code`public bool IsAuthenticated
    {
       get { return Convert.ToBoolean(Session["sIsAuthenticated"] ?? false); }
       set { Session["sIsAuthenticated"] = value; }
    }`code`

Comment: Now I have another problem, my page is displaying this instead of hyperlink..
[ <a href='/Login.aspx'>Log In</a> ]

Comment: Now, When I click the log out link, the log out link is not reverted back to log in.. What I should do now?

Comment: When you click on the Logout.aspx link then you should kill the session on the Logout's page-load code behind. like the code above.